# How to custom fullcalendar using Vue Js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, fullcalendar

**Problem:**

I have problem to customize my *Full calendar view*.

**What I want to do:**

I wanna make default view as ***month***. 
However, I can do it using `JQuery`, but I was wondering how can I use `Vue-js`  to do the same thing?

**My research effort:**

**My JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar("changeView", "month");
});
```

**My Vue.js Code**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      eventSources: [
        {
          events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/events").then(response => {
              callback(response.data.data);
            });
          },
          color: "yellow",
          textColor: "black",
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
```

How do I achive the same thing I am doing using `Jquery` by `Vue.js` code?

Comment: Can you provide your view where you use full-calendar component, and I will solve that for you.

Comment: If you are prepared to upgrade to fullCalendar 4 then integration with Vue becomes much easier because of the ready made component: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with: `defaultView: 'month'`

You should have something like this in your view:

```
<full-calendar :config="calendarConfig"/>
```

And in your `data` you need to set your config:

```
data () {
      return {
         calendarConfig: {
            defaultView: 'month'
         }
    }
}
```

#### Note

If you are using `v4` you can [check doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultView).